# How to use Wirecloud sth-source operator

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud, fiware-sth-comet

I have found a STH-Comet wirecloud operator(https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/sth-source-operator). Now how can i use this operator in my mashup and which operator/widget i have to use to provide it data.Also, in which widget i can use sth-comet output. I also have no idea of it's wiring.for e.g: it have a input endpoint i.e. Entity, how this Entity endpoint get data from my orion i mean which widget/operator i have to connect with it,s input endpoint to get input.Same with the output endpoint for e.g. it have 2 o/p endpoints i.e. Values,Timestamp in which widget/operator i can use these endpoint output.Is there any GUI wirecloud widget which can show my sth-comet output.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any Suggestion on above Query!!

Answer (score 0):

In general you need a operator to extract data from STH-Comet (that operator have the query to obtain the data), then connect this operator with a widget to show the data obtained.
In this case, I think that you can fill the operator's preferences, and keep empty the inputendpoint. In the preferences, "Entity" can be empty, only fill it if you want obtain data from a particular dispositive.
The outputs of this operator are the data obtained from STH, so you can connect these outputs with a widget for show the data (for example in a table), if you don't found the appropiate widget, you can make it.

You can see the config.xml of sth-source-operator in https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/sth-source-operator/blob/develop/src/config.xml

I hope this help you!

Comment: Hi @FabioSuarez but i think there are also some problem with sth-comet operator like its also not showing correct output.I have upload sth-comet operator in my workspace and get this error:Error: Unexpected response from STH .When i open this operator in chrome browser in developer mode to see error log then i see it tries to get response form this Url :https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/proxy/http/<my Sth-comet-IP:8666/STH/v1/contextEntities/type/Room/id/Room1/attributes/Temperature?lastN=864000&dateFrom=2018-07-23T05%3A57%3A32.563Z which shows error attach in this url: https://imgur.com/a/sywFAj8

Comment: Error in imgur.com/a/sywFAj8 sounds a permision error. I don't use fiware lab, but need you an account right? Do you try to get data with api? Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/blob/master/doc/manuals/raw-data-retrieval.md

Comment: Thanks for your help.Yeah i try the same thing with api and it's working fine.but when i use this operator in my wirecloud then it's didn't show the desire output.It add something like :https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/proxy/<STH-comet-GET_API_URL> in the URL.You have to go on this URL:https://account.lab.fiware.org/auth/login/ to make an account on fiware lab and then go to mashup section to use global wirecloud instance to make an workspace and use any widget/operator.Kindly let me know in case of any concern.